# how to stop make -n from echoing same command multiple times

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am using GNU make and have a `Makefile` which looks like this:

```
AB = A.txt B.txt

${AB}: makeAB.py
    python makeAB.py

C.txt: ${AB} makeC.py
    python makeC.py
```

When I type `make -n C.txt`, assuming `makeAB.py` needs to run, I get the output:

```
python makeAB.py
python makeAB.py
python makeC.py
```

Is there any way to write the `Makefile` so that the line `python makeAB.py` is not repeated? This is just a toy example, but in my actual application `AB` consists of many files, so I potentially get a whole screen of unnecessary output.

p.s. When called without `-n`, `make` (sensibly) only runs `python makeAB.py` once. So my problem is just with `make -n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double output arises because the recipe is scheduled to run twice, once to build `A.txt` and again to build `B.txt`.  This is normal behavior for `make`.  In particular a rule such as your (as expanded) ...

```
A.txt B.txt: makeAB.py
    python makeAB.py
```

... means that *each* of those two targets can be built via the associated recipe, not that a single execution of the recipe builds both (regardless of whether a single run does build both).  It is 100% equivalent to:

```
A.txt: makeAB.py
    python makeAB.py

B.txt: makeAB.py
    python makeAB.py
```

> When called without `-n`, `make` (sensibly) only runs `python makeAB.py` once. So my problem is just with `make -n`.

When you run with `-n`, `make` does not execute the recipe, so it cannot evaluate whether doing so to update (say) `A.txt` might also update `B.txt`.  All it knows is that both targets are out of date, so it outputs the recipes that would be executed to update each one.  This is completely sensible.

When you run `make` without `-n`, it has the opportunity to to observe that after updating one of `A.txt` and `B.txt`, the other is up to date.  It might very naturally not even have noticed that the other was initially out of date.  Having observed this, of course it does not execute the recipe again.  The output would be clearer about what was happening if the recipe executions expressed which target was being built.  For example, try this variation on the rule, which is more like how a multiple-target rule would ordinarily be written.

```
A.txt B.txt: makeAB.py
    python makeAB.py $@
```

---

So, both `make` outputs are right in their own ways. Arguably, however, the makefile is wrong, because it does not capture the expectation and fact that running the recipe once would generate both outputs.  This is a situation that the makefile language traditionally has difficulty expressing, and you will find other question about that here on SO and elsewhere.

If you are using a new enough version of GNU Make, then you can make use of its concept of ["grouped target" rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Multiple-Targets), which addresses exactly this issue.  By using `&:` as the separator in the first line of the rule, you communicate (only to pretty recent versions of GNU Make) that one execution of the rule creates all the designated targets.  Example:

```
A.txt B.txt &: makeAB.py
    python makeAB.py
```

Traditional `make`s and older GNU Make will just interpret the `&` as another target name.  That means that those `make`s will accept such makefiles, but not behave the same as recent GNU make.  Among other things, it means that if asked to build target `&`, they would try to do so, quite possibly with a surprising effect owing to the special significance of `&` to the shell.

Comment: Thanks. I have make 3.81, which is quite old (current is 4.3), and does not seem to support that feature. I am not sure why I have such an old version (4.0 came out in 2013), perhaps that is what shipped with Mac OS? So I am still thinking about the best way forward.

Comment: MacOS will never provide a newer version of GNU make than 3.81.  Just like it will never provide a newer version of bash than the absolutely ancient (and buggy) 3.2.x.  That's because in the next release after this, these GNU projects moved to license their code under the GPLv3 and Apple is virulently opposed to that license.  If you want newer versions then either get an operating system produced by a supplier not as crappy as Apple, or use macports or brew to install a newer version of GNU make (or build it yourself from source).